# How to solution erro CS1660 in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a `delegate` expression, and i would like to put a `lambda` expression in it, however this returns an error. Is there any way to do this conversion?

> this error: Cannot convert anonymous method block to type 'type' because it is not a delegate type

> This error will occur if you try to assign or cast an anonymous method block to a type that is not a delegate type.

```csharp
private void DriverAuto_CheckAllDone()
{
    this.stopwatch.Stop();
    this.Invoke((Delegate) (() => {
        this.btnExExist.Enabled = true;
        this.btnExNonExisst.Enabled = true;
        this.btnStart.Enabled = false;
        this.btnSelectFile.Enabled = true;
        this.tmrElapsed.Stop();
        this.pnlback2.Visible = false;
        this.tmrProgress2.Stop();
        this.lblTime.Text =
            this.stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss");
    }));
}
```

Comment: You can try old school *anonymous method*: `delegate() {...}`

Comment: in .Net Core 6 the code compiles

Comment: Yeah I don't see right off what the issue is, other than maybe the cast to Delegate? Depending on your version of .NET/C# you probably don't need the cast, maybe try getting rid of the cast? `.Invoke( () => {  /* do your stuff */ } );`?